# Detect event click completition

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to run a custom function when the user clicks with the mouse on a div_content_editable to put the focus in there. The problem is i want to run the fuction only when the focus as been add by the default behavior from the click function.

`$('#chat_box').on('click','.chat_textarea',function(event){
    custom_function();
});`

My custom function is to add something after the focus as been placed, but the custom function runs before the focus from the click action completes, so i need to detect when this focus action as been completed for then i can call/run my custom function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean when `textarea` is focus, you need to call a function (callback) ?

Comment: Maybe you should just listen for focus event instead of click? Or you can set focus programatically using HTMLElement.focus() inside your click listener.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#chat_box').on('click','.chat_textarea',function(event){
    if ($(this).is(':focus')){
        custom_function();
    }
});
```